# Webpack import mutual JS file only once

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have e.g. three JS files:

1. utils.js
2. file1.js
3. file2.js

The code of utils.js is not important, it contains some commonly used functions. Both other files import some of them, e.g.:

file1.js

```js
import { function1, function3 } from 'utils.js'
```

file2.js

```js
import { function1, function2 } from 'utils.js'
```

Now, when I include scripts file1.js and file2.js in one html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webpacked/file1.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webpacked/file2.bundle.js"></script>
```

The content of utils.js is executed twice (via each bundle). Is possible to suppress such behaviour? Of course in reality it is more complicated and utils.js is executed many times.

P.S.: I have tried to suppress redefinitions of utils functions using some condition like

```js
if (typeof window.function1 === 'undefined') {
    export function function1() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

but of course it is not working because export and import has to be top level.

Comment: Create one bundle and include only this one bundle with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/webpacked/file.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: I was thinking about some "workaround". I can wrap whole utils.js source code into the object. In file1.js and file2.js I will import only this object and I will be able to use its functions. All executions I can put into some init() function and I can call it in each html. But I don't like it very much. What do you think about it?

Comment: Almost every project has one  bundle. I've never seen a project with more than one include in the last 10 years. I don't understand why you use multiple bundles.

Comment: @jabaa Ok, it would be possible, but what about dynamically loaded JS? Should I create one big bundle with all JS scripts that can be loaded in one HTML and put this one big bundle into this HTML? If I do it, it could be very slow in the loading time - many files will be packed into one bundle. Is it possible to load `file1.bundle.js` and `file2.bundle.js` dynamically but `utils.js` only once? I hope I am explaining it clearly.

Comment: Lazy loaded modules usually use JSON, not HTML to be loaded. You still have one included bundle in the HTML and this bundle can load other modules. These other modules use the same `utils.js` that is already loaded by the bundle: https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Could you move your first comment as an answer to be marked? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one bundle and include only this one bundle with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webpacked/file.bundle.js"></script>
```

You can use Webpacks's lazy loading to split this bundle into separate modules and load them on demand.